# I need to handle the onkeypress event in react-native ios gifted chat

Tags: react-native

1.I'm using react-native Gifted chat 
2.I want to use on-Key press event on text-input gifted chat
3.But i have no idea how to deal with them
What's possible solution ?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [docs](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat#props), you simply pass in an `onKeyPress` callback via the `textInputProps` prop to GiftedChat.

Say you have a callback with name `onKeyPress` in your component, you'd:

```
  render () {
     return (
       <GiftedChat
           messages={messages}
           textInputProps={{
               onKeyPress: this.onKeyPress.bind(this)
           }}
       />
     )
  }
```